# Event dispatcher in bash (Ubuntu Gnu/Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, files, monitoring

Are there any methods or bash tools that can observe some events (such as creating a folder) and then do another actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `inotify`, there are programs `inotifywait` and `inotifywatch`, in package `inotify-tools`.

You can add event handlers to creates, reads, writes, deletes, etc.

To install: `sudo apt-get install inotify-tools`

see also package `inotify-hookable`